# protractor test timed out on Chrome but not on FF

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, angularjs-e2e

I'm running a protractor test.
there is a login part which is not Angular and then the home page which is  Angular part.
after passing the login part - on Chrome I get a Timeout, but on FF it continues successfully. 
it used to run also on Chrome before, and a friend using Robot Framework doesn't get to timeout even when using chrome.

error message:

```
 timeout: timed out after 30000 msec waiting for spec to complete
```

I've tries also adding

```
defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000
```

but it didn't help. it's just keep waiting.

config.js:

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
    // 'browserName': 'firefox' 
},

specs: ['*/loginEAPTest.js'],

params: {
    login: {
        user: '****',
        password: '****'
    }
},

resultJsonOutputFile: 'TestResults/Test.js',

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    //defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000,
    includeStackTrace: true
},


onPrepare: function() {


// for non-angular page
 browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

}

};
```

loginEAPTest.js:

```
var LoginPage = require('../global/LoginPage');
var capture = require('../global/screenshots');

describe('login Testing', function () {

var login = new LoginPage();

beforeEach(function(){

        login.get();
        login.justClickLogin();
    }
);

it('Should login using Email & Password', function () {
browser.sleep(10000);
  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName_str')).sendKeys ("****");
   browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys("******");
   browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'Log In')]")).click();
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
browser.sleep(5000);
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
expect(element(by.css('[data-ui-sref=myApps]')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
});
});
```

LoginPage.js (relevant part):

```
   this.justClickLogin = function() {
    var loginObj = this;
    loginObj.signInButton.click().then(function () {
        console.log("press login");
        var loginframe = element(by.tagName('iframe'));
        console.log("before switch");
        browser.switchTo().frame(0);
        console.log("after switch");
        browser.sleep(4000);


    });

};
```

thanks.

Comment: On which line timeout occurs? Thanks.

Comment: between     browser.switchTo().defaultContent();  to
expect(element(by.css('[data-ui-sref=myApps]')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);